# Aggregate objects and boundaries

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

I am confused about aggregate objects and that only aggregate objects have repositories because I don't know how to properly code it.

Assume that you have a `User`, `Question` and `QuestionLog` entity. I don't understand how to set the boundaries for how much you should put in an aggregate object. You could say that no questions would live in my system without a user, and a questionlog would not exist if it had no questions to be attached to. So would user be an aggregate root?

How would you add a questionlog then for instance?
For me it seems like you end up with a lot of nesting etc. `User.addQuestionLog`? I don't understand where the boundaries go for when it should be an aggregate and seen as a unit? For me it would be more natural that `User` is one aggregate and `Question` is another. However I don't understand how to actually know this.

And a question can have categories too, would the category also be a part of question or not? Why/why not? How to spot them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of the objects, DDD is all about real life.

The real questions are:

- Can X exist whithout Y?
- Is Y a part of X?

Hence:

- Can a user exist without a question? **Yes**
- Should the question still be available if the user quits? **Yes**
- Is a log part of a user? **No**
- Is a log part of a question? **No** (since it belongs to users, but is not part of a user)
- Is a category part of a question? **Typically yes**

So we end up with three root aggregates.

The category is value object

Comment: But woulnd't a question log be a part of a question since it contains information about what wrong with that partixular question etc? Could you please give more examples and description?

Comment: And are the two questions you listed related to the concept in my particular domain?

Comment: How would I know how your domain works or what constraints it has? It's just examples on how you can think.

Comment: I kinda disagree about the category part. A question belongs to (is placed into) a category, at best a question has tags (it's tagged). Of course, it does matter what the OP understands by 'category' and only depending of that definition we can say exactly if a category is indeed a value object.